# Variable outside of for loop being changed?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am using a Java `ArrayList` to create array lists, and edit them using the methods given from `java.util.ArrayList`. Our teacher has us doing various things all like removing integers in the list and placing them elsewhere.

The final step in our problem set is to take the array that has been edited throughout the class, copy it into a new array (my variable for the new array is `newArrayList`), take all the even integers out of the array list that the new list was copied from, and then print out the old one WITHOUT the even integers and the new one copied from the old one WITH the even integers side by side.

The old list with even integers being `removed = pics`
The new list being copied from the old list without the even integers being `removed = newpics`

I ran a for loop for the size of the `ArrayList` with a nested if statement inside for identifying even variables. In the results printed out, `newpics` seems to lose its even integers along with `pics`, and when I print them out at the end they are both missing even integers. I only want `pics` to be missing even integers, and `newpics` seems to get altered somewhere in the for loop even though I don't even MENTION it in the for loop. I have had multiple people look at this and it is extremely frustrating.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class ArrayList here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class ArrayListTester
{

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     * 
     * @param  y   a sample parameter for a method
     * @return     the sum of x and y 
     */
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        ArrayList <Integer> pics = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<6;i++)
        {
            pics.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Original ArrayList" +pics);

        System.out.println("__________________________________");

        int secondlasttoFirst = pics.get(4);
        pics.remove(4);
        pics.add(0,secondlasttoFirst);
        System.out.println("Penultimate moved to front" +pics);

        System.out.println("__________________________________");

        int firsttoLast = pics.get(0);
        pics.remove(0);
        pics.add(5, firsttoLast);
        System.out.println("First moved to end" +pics);

        System.out.println("__________________________________");

        int fronttoBack = pics.get(0);
        int backtoFront = pics.get(5);
        pics.remove(0);
        pics.add(0, backtoFront);
        pics.remove(5);
        pics.add(5, fronttoBack);
        System.out.println("Swapped first and last" +pics);

        System.out.println("__________________________________");

        ArrayList <Integer> newpics = new ArrayList <Integer>();      
        newpics = pics;
        System.out.println("newArrayList" +newpics);

        System.out.println("__________________________________");




        int j=0;
        for (j=0; j<pics.size();j++)
        {

            if (pics.get(j) % 2 ==0)
            {
                pics.remove(j);

            }
        }



        System.out.println("Original with evens removed" +pics);
        System.out.println("__________________________________");
        System.out.println("Original newArrayList" +newpics);

    }
}
```

Comment: you meant the Java ArrayList API :)

Comment: You shouldn't remove from a list while iterating over it

Answer (score 1):

When you say `newpics = pics`, you just make a new variable that points to the same actual thing. Maybe you should consider making a... clone?

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CopyingandCloningListspublicObjectclone.htm

Answer (score 0):

In java, when you say `something = somethingelse`, you are really storing a reference to that object. That is to say, `something` will have the same address as something else. Therefore, the changes are to the samething.

Checkout this easier example:

**Code:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Make an array
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        // And a copy to it...
        // This is just copy of the address
        ArrayList<String> copy = strings;
        // Add to strings
        strings.add("Hi");
        // Add to copy
        copy.add("my");
        // Add to strings
        strings.add("name");
        // Add to copy
        copy.add("is");
        // Add to strings
        strings.add("bob");

        // No matter which one you print, youll get the same string because they are referncing the same thing
        System.out.println(copy);
        // > [Hi, my, name, is, bob]
        System.out.println(strings);
        // > [Hi, my, name, is, bob]


    }
```

Notice how I alternated adding stuff, yet both of them ended with same result.

Here is how you can do an actual copy:

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Make an array
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add to strings
    strings.add("Hi");
    // Add to strings
    strings.add("name");
    // Add to strings
    strings.add("bob");
    // Now you want a copy
    ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(strings);
    // now changes to copy, are only to copy
    copy.add("change just to copy");

    System.out.println(strings);
    // > [Hi, name, bob]
    System.out.println(copy);
    // > [Hi, name, bob, change just to copy]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do mention the other list in the loop because `newpics = pics`... You make `newpics` *reference* `pics`. In other words, they are the same object, so changes to one are reflected in the other.

If you would like to not have that happen, simply change

```
ArrayList <Integer> newpics = new ArrayList <Integer>();      
newpics = pics;
```

To this

```
ArrayList <Integer> newpics = new ArrayList <Integer>(pics);
```

---

Additionally, calling `list.remove()` while iterating over it an checking its size can cause some side-effects like skipping elements. You can get around that by using an iterator.

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = pics.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    int pic = iter.next();
    if (pic % 2 ==0)
    {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```